# Type kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsResourceLoader is defined multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I wanted to enable ProGuard, so I made the **minifyEnabled** variable true in my **build.gradle** file.

However, I could not get APK buil in any way, I got the following error every time:

```
Type kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsResourceLoader is defined multiple times:

META-INF/versions/9/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class
```

***The methods I tried to solve the problem:***

- Clearing Android Studio Cache and project cache.
- After extracting the project as ZIP, extracting it in a different place and opening it from scratch.
- Add this rule to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialisation.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsResourceLoader { *; }
```

- Add this to packagingOptions:

```
exclude 'META-INF/versions/9/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class'
```

- Changing the Kotlin version from 1.8.20 to 1.8.22.

**None of the methods worked.**

I generally use ktor for dependencies, not sure if this is a problem for proguard.

**My Dependencies:**

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7")

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-gson:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jwt:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cors:2.3.4")

    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")

    
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")

    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
```